# loop to check for property on object

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

how would i go about constructing a loop that keeps going with a small delay, this loop would check if an object property is not = null, the loop would timeout after x seconds.

The thing is i am waiting for another object to set a HTTP response property, is this bad practise or?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to keep polling the object? Have you thought of KVO (Key Value Observing?):

```
[self.yourObject addObserver: self forKeyPath: @"objectProperty" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context: nil];
```

and then:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == yourObject) {

        //Check property is not nil
    }
}
```

and

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    [yourObject removeObserver: self forKeyPath: @"objectProperty"];
}
```

See the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for changes in a property, you can use Key-Value Observing (KVO), that's what it's for.

Basically :

```
[theObjectHavingTheProperty addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"propertyName" options:0 context:nil];
```

Don't forget to remove the observer on dealloc.

Then this method will be called whenever the property changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```